# SwiftとQuickを使って、ボタンを押すとラベルの表示が変わるUIテストをしたい

Tags: ios, swift

Quickを使ってテストがうまくいきません。どうしてでしょうか？

ボタンを押すとラベルに「Hello」と表示する機能をテストしたいのです。

### 作業環境

- Mac OS X 10.10
- Xcode 6.3.2 (Swift 1.2)

### StoryBoard

[image: StoryBoard]

上のラベルオブジェクト「????」が`myLabel`です。
下のボタンオブジェクト「Button」が`myButton`です。

### テスト対象のViewController

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var myButton: UIButton!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    @IBAction func pushButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.myLabel.text = "Hello"
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

### テストの内容

```
import UIKit
import Quick
import Nimble
import TestApp

class ViewControllerSpec: QuickSpec {
    override func spec() {
        var vc : ViewController!
        beforeEach{
            vc = ViewController()
        }
        describe("ボタンを押す") {
            beforeEach{
                vc.beginAppearanceTransition(true, animated: false)
                vc.endAppearanceTransition()
            }
            it("myLabelのtextが変わる") {
                vc.myButton?.sendActionsForControlEvents(UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
                expect(vc.myLabel?.text).to(equal("Hello"))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### テスト結果

> failed - expected to equal , got  (user beNil() to match nils)

`vc.beginAppearanceTransition(true, animated: false)` と `vc.endAppearanceTransition()` によって、`viewDidAppear` されているので、`vc.myLabel`には`nil`が含まれないという認識なんですが、どうして`got <nil>`と返ってくるのかわかりません。

教えてください。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myLabel`および`myButton`はStoryBoardによって設定されるので、`vc = ViewController()`のようにStoryBoardを使わずに直接クラスをインスタンス化しているため、`nil`のままなのです。

ビューコントローラをインスタンス化しているところをStoryBoardからインスタンス化するように変えれば動くと思いますよ。

```
vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle(forClass: ViewController.self)).instantiateInitialViewController() as! ViewController
```

Comment: 上記をヒントに、このコード↓でテストできました。ありがとうございました。

Comment: `var storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle(forClass: ViewController.self))  
    vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewControllerID") as! ViewController`

Comment: あ、そうですね。テストケースから実行する場合はメインバンドルが変わるのを失念していました。